# Замена вектора декой

Tags: c++

Помогите понять в чем проблема:

Имеется тип с определением `typedef std::vector<std::vector<chtype>> TetrisScreen;`. Так как зачастую приходится добавлять в начало новые элементы (`vector<chtype>`) я решил заменить определение типа на `typedef std::deque<std::vector<chtype>> TetrisScreen;`, но получил проблему. В функции:

```
unsigned short Tetris::delete_all_solutions()
{
unsigned short rezult {};
for (auto i {screen_.begin()}; i != screen_.end(); ++i) {
    int counter {};
    for (auto j {i->begin()}; j != i->end(); ++ j) {
        if (*j == DEF_VALUE) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter == i->size()) {
        ++lines_;
        ++rezult;
        screen_.erase(i);
        screen_.push_front(decltype(screen_)::value_type (i->size(), DEF_VALUE));//insert(screen_.begin(), decltype(screen_)::value_type (i->size(), DEF_VALUE));
    }
}
return rezult;
}
```

возникает ошибка, которая приводит к краху программы. До этого все работало (в функции изменилась всего одна строка, предыдущее ее состояние закоментировано).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в цикле по `screen_` добавляете в него новые элементы. При этом итераторы становятся невалидными и программа закономерно падает. В случае вектора это тоже могло проявляться, но скорее всего там была заранее выделенная при помощи `reserve` память  или оставшаяся от предыдущих действий. С деком такой подход не работает, т.к. нужно выделять память как минимум под два массива, а не под один и нет соответствующего интерфейса. Решение - заменить цикл по итераторам на цикл по индексам, только нужно не забыть, что при добавлении элемента в начало индекс станет указывать на предыдущий элемент и нужно сделать инкремент.

Comment: инкремент делать не нужно, так как в начало вставляется элемент и количество элементов в деке остается равным тому  же значению.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Вы правы, я не увидел erase. Из-за этого раньше программа и не падала, т.к. результирующий размер не менялся.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что проблема у вас в [erase](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase). После выполнение удаления, все последующие итераторы у вас становятся не валидными в очереди. 
Я бы вам предложил бежать по итератору не с начала, а с конца, тогда невалидные итераторы у вас не будут получаться.

```
for (auto i {screen_.end() - 1}; i >= screen_.begin(); --i)
```